# Internal error on AJAX call to a Django view (restframework endpoint)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

jQUERY:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/notify/',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              if (data.is_taken) {
                alert("A user with this username already exists.");
              }
            }
          });
```

urls.py:

```
 url(r'^notify/$', views.notify,name='notify'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import JsonResponse

def notify(request):
    data = {
        'is_taken': Notification.objects.all()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

On calling ajax in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

What may be wrong? Everything is correct and present . Django 1.8 , jQuery 3.1.0

EDIT: Django error log traceback

```
    Internal Server Error: /notify/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TheKotik/djboy/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/djboy/blog/views.py", line 212, in notify
    return JsonResponse(data)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/djboy/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 535, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/djboy/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 112, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [<Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>, <Notification: Notification object>] is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please include the details of the error (it should be on the django errors log)

Comment: @AdrianoMartins edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure your result (in your case `data`) is json serializable, note you are doing `'is_taking': Notification.objects.all()`, you should do something like this instead:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET', ]) 
def notify(request):
    data = {
        'is_taken': NotificationSerializer(Notification.objects.all(), many=True).data
    }
    return Response(data)
```

And write the [Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) e.g. `NotificationSerializer` for `Notification`

Comment: You should use the DRF Response class, not the Django JsonResponse one.

Comment: Right! I'm updating the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @trinchet thanks, complex but working on server side. it may be off topic, but how shall I handle this in JS? When I'm trying to parse, it's already an object. Otherwise when I am trying to get something out 'TypeError: undefined is not an object'

Comment: @trinchet in frontend, actually created separate question, and there was also a typo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764225/cant-get-data-out-of-serialized-python-object-in-js-jquery