# Can't get data out of serialized python object in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, serialization

It's a continuation of the issue [Internal error on AJAX call to a Django view (restframework endpoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744156/internal-error-on-ajax-call-to-a-django-view-restframework-endpoint/40744441#40744441) which was server side. Now there is a frontend problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/notify/',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: '',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.notifications) {
        console.log(data.notifiications[1].fields);

      }
    }
  });
```

Get the following error in console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.notifications')
```

On server side everything is correct, and I get whatever data I need. I supposed that I need to parse it first but when I'm trying to parse, it's already an object. Otherwise when I am trying to get something out as out of the object `TypeError: undefined is not an object`.

EDIT: There was a typo, but the problem remains. If I print it to console.log:

```
console.log(data.notifications);
```

there is nothing. But if I alert data.notifications: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

And if I go further as I mentioned like `data.notifications[1].model` or `data.notifications[1].pk` or anything else like `data.notifications[1].fields.whom` all of this must be correct theoretically but return nothing.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.notifications.fields.choice_fl')
```

EDIT2:
also tried setting fields manually

```
nots = serializers.serialize('json', Notification.objects.all(), fields=('whom','choice_afl'))
data = {
    'notifications': nots

}
return Response(data)
```

if alert  `alert(data['notifications']);` get this:

```
[{"pk": 1, "fields": {"whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F"}, "model": "blog.notification"}, {"pk": 2, "fields": {"whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F"}, "model": "blog.notification"}, {"pk": 3, "fields": {"whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F"}, "model": "blog.notification"}, {"pk": 4, "fields": {"whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F"}, "model": "blog.notification"}, {"pk": 5, "fields": {"whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F"}, "model": "blog.notification"}, {"pk": 6, "fields": {"whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F"}, "model": "blog.notification"}, {
```

And as previously whatever I enter further, it's undefined

Comment: do my eyes spot a typo inside your console.log?

Comment: @KevinKloet sorry, but I don't understand what is issue then

Comment: notifiications should be notifications

Comment: @Vinand compare `data.notifications` to `data.notifiications`

Comment: Set 'dataType' param to 'json' in your request params

Comment: @ValeriyGaydar edited typo and dataType, still getting the same error

Comment: @Vinand , do you have 'notifications' key in your json data?

Comment: @ValeriyGaydar yes, I checked via  'if(data.hasOwnProperty('notifications')){
alert('yes');
}'

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
console.log(data.notifiications[1].fields);
```

should be:

```
console.log(data.notifications[1].fields);
```

Comment: You don't have "notification" in your object. This picture is bad, it would be more readable if it was a text.

Comment: If console.log 'data.notifications' there is nothing. But if I alert data.notifications: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'

Comment: change dataType: '' to dataType:'json'

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure what was wrong, but this works just fine

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/notify/',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        alert(data['notifications']);
         var sed = JSON.parse(data['notifications'])
        alert(sed[2].fields.choice_afl);

    }
  });
```

And in backend,as in EDIT2:

```
 nots = serializers.serialize('json', Notification.objects.all(), fields=('whom','choice_afl'))
data = {
    'notifications': nots

}
return Response(data)
```